# In pandas, How to select the rows that contains NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have the following dataframe in `df`:

```
a     | b     | c
------+-------+-------
5     | 2     | 4
NaN   | 6     | 8
5     | 9     | 0
3     | 7     | 1
```

If I do `df.loc[df['a'] == 5]` it will correctly return the first and third row, but then if I do a `df.loc[df['a'] == np.NaN]` it returns nothing.

I think this is more a python thing than a pandas one. If I compare `np.nan` against anything, even `np.nan == np.nan` will evaluate as `False`, so the question is, how should I test for `np.nan`?

Comment: The target is a little more complicated but basically you do the null checking with `df['a'].isnull()` or `pd.isnull(df['a'])`. And the selection is easy after that: `df[df['a'].isnull()]`

Comment: you can use numpy.isnan() which gives you a boolean array of the same shape as the input array

Comment: In general, I'd avoid using `np.isnan` on DataFrames.  It's not as robust as `pd.isnull`, which has the same functionality.  For example, compare what happens when you try `np.isnan(df['a'])`  with `pd.isnull(df['a'])` when `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['x', np.nan, 'y']})`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I used both `ìsnull()` and `isnan()` and got the same results that did what I wanted. Why you didn't post your answers as answers?

Comment: This tutorial could be helpful: https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-check-if-any-value-is-nan-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using isnull like so:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    a=[1,2,3,np.nan,5,6,7]
    df = pd.DataFrame(a)

    df[df[0].isnull()]
```